# Convert IST date format to YYYY-MM-DD in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a date string "`Wed Mar 19 00:30:00 IST 1997`" and I want to make this as readable **YYYY-MM-DD** format. Is there any solution to do this with pure javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your time is not normal javascript date string. if you remove the `IST` from your string, you can create a date object from it.

```
dateString = 'Wed Mar 19 00:30:00 IST 1997';
var date = new Date(dateString.replace('IST', ''));

let day = date.getDate();
let month = date.getMonth()+1;
let year = date.getFullYear();

console.log(year+"/"+month+"/"+day)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the following function

```js
let str = "Wed Mar 19 00:30:00 IST 1997"

function formatDate(date) {
  date = date.split(" ");
  let monthsList = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];

  let year = date[5];
  let month = `0${(monthsList.indexOf(date[1]) + 1)}`.slice(-2);
  let day = date[2];

  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}

console.log(formatDate(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```js
 let date = new Date(); 
    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth()+1;
    let year = date.getFullYear();

    console.log(year+"/"+month+"/"+day)
```

Comment: but where do I put the date string which I'm getting through api?

Comment: let date = new Date("Wed Mar 19 00:30:00 IST 1997");  done this and I got NaN/NaN/NaN

Comment: That's not really what the OP has asked for. You are using the current date but the string is missing.